# Order by descending is not working on LINQ to Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Order by descending is not working on LINQ to Entity
In the following Query In place of ascending If I keep descending it is not working. Please help me out

```
var hosters =
    from e in context.Hosters_HostingProviderDetail
    where e.ActiveStatusID == pendingStateId
    orderby e.HostingProviderName ascending
    select e;

return hosters.ToList();
```

Comment: "it is not working" is incredibly vague. Please be more descriptive.

Comment: When i say ascending it is returning the result, but when I say descending it is giving 0 rows

Comment: then it is working, but you get no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should return correct result.  It is working fine for me.

```
var hosters = 
from e in context.Hosters_HostingProviderDetail 
where e.ActiveStatusID == pendingStateId 
orderby e.HostingProviderName **descending**
select e; 

return hosters.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a lambda expression to get the same result:

```
return context.Hosters_HostingProviderDetail.Where(e => e.ActiveStatusID == pendingStateID).OrderByDescending(e => e.HostingProviderName).ToList();
```